# extract feature vectors from binarised image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have a two similar binarised images of an object.

[image: Image1] [image: Image2]

I want to extract feature vectors from these two images and compare them using knn algorithm.

I have referred to [Extract feature vector from 2d image in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49180941/extract-feature-vector-from-2d-image-in-numpy) Code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

src = cv2.imread("4.jpg")
target_size = (64,64)

dst = cv2.resize(src, target_size)
dst = dst.reshape(target_size.shape[0] * target_size.shape[1])
```

However I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-288728d7a111> in <module>
----> 1 dst = dst.reshape(target_size.shape[0] * target_size.shape[1])

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I tried resolving this error using

```
preprocess(numpy.array(target_size))
```

But still the error persists, is there anyway I can remove this error ?

Comment: I guess it's just `target_size[0] * target_size[1]` instead of `target_size.shape[0] * target_size.shape[1]`. `target_size` is a tuple, and has no attribute `shape` - as the error message also suggests...

Comment: When I try your solution I get : "ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12288 into shape (4096,)"

Comment: Ah, you have 3-channel images... then you need `target_size[0] * target_size[1] * 3`, which is 12288. But you write, you have binarized images!?

Comment: Yes, I. have binarised image, Ive updated my image in above question

Comment: If you want to force working with grayscale images, use `src = cv2.imread("4.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`.

Comment: my images attached are binarised using OTSU transform. I believe they are not greyscale

Comment: What Hans is saying is that `cv2.imread("4.jpg")` returns a color image (it has 3 channels), if you do `cv2.imread("4.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` it will read it as a one-channel image. You should do that to avoid the "ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12288 into shape (4096,)"  error message.

Comment: Also, after saving as JPEG, it will not be a binary image any more. JPEG compression means that new gray values will be introduced.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I tried "cv2.imread("4.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)". But I am getting error : cannot reshape array of size 489300 into shape (4096,)

Comment: So you are saying that reading as a color image you had 12288 values, and reading as gray-value you have 489300? You likely changed the image file then.

Comment: Or did you forget the `resize`?

Comment: Reading image as a colour image "src = cv2.imread("4.jpg")" I get: cannot reshape array of size 1467900 into shape (4096,). And reading the image as grayscale image "src = cv2.imread("4.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)" I get : cannot reshape array of size 489300 into shape (4096,). I didn't forget to resize